# tensor contraction ten1_Air with ten2_Ckr

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to contract such tensors ten1_Air with ten2_Ckr, where i = k, to obtain tensor test_ACi

I thought that in the case when i = k, the correct einsum would be:

```
test_ACi = np.einsum('Air,Cir->ACi',ten1_Air,ten2_Ckr)
```

However, it seems that the right form is:

```
test_ACi = np.einsum('Air,Ckr->ACi',ten1_Air,ten2_Ckr)
```

Which of these contractions is correct and why? I'd be grateful for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
'Air,Cir->ACi'
```

the `i` dimension essentially passes through - though moved to the end.  The `r` dimension is the one that is summed (as in matrix product).  In conventional `dot` format this would be

```
loop on i:
    dot(Ar, rC)
```

With

```
'Air,Ckr->ACi'
```

A, C, r behave the same.  `i` passes through.  'k' is summed, as in `ten2_Ckr.sum(axis=1)`

The basic rule is that dimensions that appear on the left but not the right are summed.  Summing is different depending on where they appear in just one of the left side or both.  Other dimensions pass through, some behaving more like a 'batch' dimension, others like an 'outer' pair.